# Python: Why is __getattr__ catching AttributeErrors?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm struggling with `__getattr__`. I have a complex recursive codebase, where it is important to let exceptions propagate.

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        raise AttributeError('lala')

    def __getattr__(self, name):     
        print('attr: ', name)
        return 1      

print(A().a)
```

Results in:

```
('attr: ', 'a')
1
```

Why this behaviour? Why is no exception thrown? This behaviour is not documented ([`__getattr__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#object.__getattr__)). `getattr()` could just use `A.__dict__`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would say that the failure of the documentation is that it states that `AttributeError` can be raised in `__get__` (which is what you are effectively doing here) but doesn't explain what effect that has.  It should probably say that `AttributeError` signals to python that it should behave as if the attribute has not been found (so that `__getattr__` is tried as a backup, as usual) - if that isn't the behaviour you want, then you should raise something else.

Answer (score 9):

I just changed the code to

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        print "trying property..."
        raise AttributeError('lala')
    def __getattr__(self, name):     
        print('attr: ', name)
        return 1      

print(A().a)
```

and, as we see, indeed the property is tried first. But as it claims not to be there (by raising `AttributeError`), `__getattr__()` is called as "last resort".

It is not documented clearly, but can maybe be counted under "Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places".

Comment: and what is the recommended way to do this instead? Not using properties or using `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`?

Comment: I would say not raising `AttributeError`, or handling that case in `__getattr__`, or using `__getattribute__` and call `super(...).__getattribute__`, catching the `AttributeError`.

Comment: I can't fathom why you'd ever want to raise `AttributeError` explicitly in a property. Or anywhere other than a `__(get|set)attr[ibute]__` method, really.

Comment: Explicitly raising an AttributeError is not what this is about... The problem is, that I have a complex program, wherein an AttributeError is raised (due to programming mistakes), but I don't know where, because `__getattr__` hides it from me.

Comment: @glglgl: It's not like I raise an `AttributeError`, I just make programming mistakes (accessing a non existing attribute). At the end I don't see anything, because it was catched by `__getattr__`.

Comment: Depending on what happens then, `__getattr__` handles this. If you know which attributes we talk about, you could raise an exception (maybe an assertion?)  in `__getattr__`, maybe just for the time of debugging, in order to find the place where the invalid attribute access happens.

Answer (score 9):

Using `__getattr__` and properties in the same class is dangerous, because it can lead to errors that are very difficult to debug.

If the getter of a property throws `AttributeError`, then the `AttributeError` is silently caught, and `__getattr__` is called. Usually, this causes `__getattr__` to fail with an exception, but if you are extremely unlucky, it doesn't, and you won't even be able to easily trace the problem back to `__getattr__`.

EDIT: Example code for this problem can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921010/2279059).

Unless your property getter is trivial, you can never be 100% sure it won't throw `AttributeError`. The exception may be thrown several levels deep.

Here is what you could do:

1. Avoid using properties and `__getattr__` in the same class.
2. Add a `try ... except` block to all property getters that are not trivial
3. Keep property getters simple, so you know they won't throw `AttributeError`
4. Write your own version of the `@property` decorator, which catches `AttributeError` and re-throws it as `RuntimeError`.

See also http://blog.devork.be/2011/06/using-getattr-and-property_17.html

EDIT: In case anyone is considering solution 4 (which I don't recommend), it can be done like this:

```
def property_(f):
    def getter(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise RuntimeError, "Wrapped AttributeError: " + str(e), sys.exc_info()[2]

    return property(getter)
```

Then use `@property_` instead of `@property` in classes that override `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 6):

[`__getattribute__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) says:

> If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

I read this (by *inclusio unius est exclusio alterius*) as saying that attribute access **will** call `__getattr__` if `object.__getattribute__` (which is "*called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses*") happens to raise `AttributeError` - whether directly or inside a descriptor `__get__` (e.g. a property fget); note that [`__get__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) should "*return the (computed) attribute value or raise an `AttributeError` exception*".

As an analogy, operator special methods can raise `NotImplementedError` whereupon the other operator methods (e.g. `__radd__` for `__add__`) will be tried.

Answer (score 4):

`__getattr__` is called when an attribute access fails with an AttributeError. Maybe this is why you think it 'catches' the errors. However, it doesn't, it's Python's attribute access functionality that catches them, and then calls `__getattr__`.

But `__getattr__` itself doesn't catch any errors. If you raise an AttributeError in `__getattr__` you  get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

regularly run into this problem because I implement `__getattr__` a lot and have lots of `@property` methods. Here's a decorator I came up with to get a more useful error message:

```
def replace_attribute_error_with_runtime_error(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except AttributeError as e:
            # logging.exception(e)
            raise RuntimeError(
                '{} failed with an AttributeError: {}'.format(f.__name__, e)
            )
    return wrapped
```

And use it like this:

```
class C(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ...

    @property
    @replace_attribute_error_with_runtime_error
    def complicated_property(self):
        ...

    ...
```

The error message of the underlying exception will include name of the class whose instance raised the underlying `AttributeError`.
You can also log it if you want to.

Comment: I have actually done something similar to work around it and called it `safe_property`. It does the same thing, just with one decorator.

Comment: If anyone wants to use the one-decorator approach, I found Dave Halter's code at https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/master/jedi/inference/utils.py

Answer (score 0):

You're doomed anyways when you combine `@property` with `__getattr__`:

```
class Paradise:
    pass

class Earth:
    @property
    def life(self):
        print('Checking for paradise (just for fun)')
        return Paradise.breasts
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print("sorry! {} does not exist in Earth".format(item))

earth = Earth()
try:
    print('Life in earth: ' + str(earth.life))
except AttributeError as e:
    print('Exception found!: ' + str(e))
```

Gives the following output:

```
Checking for paradise (just for fun)
sorry! life does not exist in Earth
Life in earth: None
```

When your real problem was with calling `Paradise.breasts`.

`__getattr__` is always called when an `AtributeError` is risen. The content of the exception is ignored.

The sad thing is that there's no solution to this problem given `hasattr(earth, 'life')` will return `True` (just because `__getattr__` is defined), but will still be reached by the attribute 'life' as it didn't exist, whereas the real underlying problem is with `Paradise.breasts`.

My partial solution involves using a try-except in `@property` blocks which are known to hit upon `AttributeError` exceptions.