# Using __getattr__ and meeting expected behaviour for subclasses

Tags: python

I am the author -- and currently almost definitely the sole user, if on multiple projects -- of [a simple database layer](https://github.com/Calama/kale/blob/master/kale.py) (inspired by [minimongo](https://github.com/slacy/minimongo)) for MongoDB called `kale`. My current use of `__getattr__` in the base class for models has led to some hard-to-track bugs.

The problem I've run into [was articulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116896/python-why-is-getattr-catching-attributeerrors) concisely last June by David Halter on this site. The discussion is interesting, however no solutions were offered.

In short:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...         print "We're here -> attribute lookup found 'a' in one of the usual places!"
...         raise AttributeError
...         return "a"
...     
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print "We're here -> attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places!"
...         print('attr: ', name)
...         return "not a"
... 
>>> print(A().a)
We're here -> attribute lookup found 'a' in one of the usual places!
We're here -> attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places!
('attr: ', 'a')
not a
>>>
```

Note that this contradictory behaviour is not what I would expect from reading [the official python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

> **`object.__getattr__(self, name)`**
>
> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the
>   usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in
>   the class tree for self). name is the attribute name.

(It would be nice if they mentioned that `AttributeError` is the means by which "attribute lookup" knows if an attribute has been found in "the usual places" or not. The clarifying parenthetical seems to me at best incomplete.)

In practice, this has caused problems tracking down bugs caused by programming errors wherever an AttributeError is raised in a `@property` descriptor thing.

```
>>> class MessedAttrMesser(object):
...     things = {
...         'one': 0,
...         'two': 1,
...     }
...     
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         try:
...             return self.things[attr]
...         except KeyError as e:
...             raise AttributeError(e)
...     
...     @property
...     def get_thing_three(self):
...         return self.three
... 
>>> 
>>> blah = MessedAttrMesser()
>>> print(blah.one)
0
>>> print(blah.two)
1
>>> print(blah.get_thing_three)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'get_thing_three'
>>>
```

In this case it's pretty obvious what's going on by inspecting the class as a whole. However, if you rely on the message from the stack trace, `AttributeError: 'get_thing_three'`, it makes no sense, since, clearly, `get_thing_three` looks to be as valid an attribute as they come.

The purpose of `kale` is to provide a base class for building models. As such, the base model code is hidden away from the end programmer, and masking the cause of errors like this is not ideal.

The end programmer (*cough* me) may choose to use `@property` descriptors on their models,  and their code should work *and* fail in the ways they would expect.

**The Question**

How can I allow `AttributeError`s to propagate through my base class which has defined `__getattr__`?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you can't --- or at least, not in simple and foolproof way.  As you noted, `AttributeError` is the mechanism Python uses to determine whether an attribute is "found in the usual places".  Although the `__getattr__` documentation doesn't mention this, it is made somewhat more clear in the documentation for `__getattribute__`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116896/python-why-is-getattr-catching-attributeerrors/11117902#11117902) to the question you already linked to.

You could override `__getattribute__` and catch `AttributeError` there, but if you caught one, you'd have no obvious way to tell whether it was a "real" error (meaning the attribute really wasn't found), or an error raised by user code during the lookup process.  In theory you could inspect the traceback looking for particular things, or do various other hacks to try to verify the attribute's existence, but these approaches are going to be more fragile and dangerous than the existing behavior.

One other possibility is to write your own descriptor that is based on `property`, but catches AttributeErrors and re-raises them as something else.  This would, however, require you to use this property-replacement instead of the builtin `property`.  In addition, it would mean that AttributeErrors raised from inside descriptor methods are not propagated as AttributeErrors but as something else (whatever you replace them with).  Here is an example:

```
class MyProp(property):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        try:
            return super(MyProp, self).__get__(obj, cls)
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError, "Property raised AttributeError"

class A(object):
    @MyProp
    def a(self):
        print "We're here -> attribute lookup found 'a' in one of the usual places!"
        raise AttributeError
        return "a"

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "We're here -> attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places!"
        print('attr: ', name)
        return "not a"

>>> A().a
We're here -> attribute lookup found 'a' in one of the usual places!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    A().a
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 6, in __get__
    raise ValueError, "Property raised AttributeError"
ValueError: Property raised AttributeError
```

Here AttributeErrors are replaced with ValueErrors.  This could be fine if all you want is to make sure the exception "breaks out" of the attribute-access mechanism and can propagate up to the next level.  But if you have complex exception-catching code that is expecting to see an AttributeError, it will miss this error, since the exception type has changed.

(Also, this example obviously only deals with property getters, not setters, but it should be clear how to extend the idea.)

I guess as an extension of this solution, you could combine this `MyProp` idea with a custom `__getattribute__`.  Basically, you could define a custom exception class, say `PropertyAttributeError`, and have the property-replacement reraise AttributeError as PropertyAttributeError.  Then, in your custom `__getattribute__`, you could catch PropertyAttributeError and re-raise it as AttributeError.  Basically the `MyProp` and the `__getattribute__` could act as a "shunt" that bypasses Python's normal handling by converting the error from AttributeError to something else, and then converting it back to AttributeError again once it's "safe" to do so.  However, my feeling is it's not worth it to do this, as `__getattribute__` can have a substantial performance impact.

One little addendum: [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1615) has been raised about this on the Python bug tracker, and there is recent activity on possible solutions, so it's possible it may be fixed in future versions.

Comment: Huh. I was skimming a bit when I read that particular answer (which deserves more upvotes!), and it's actually a great explanation of the current behaviour.
As far as writing my own property: am I making a mistake in assuming that I'd need to then enforce its use by subclasses?

Comment: @Phil: Right, you'd need to stipulate that people have to use your property replacement instead of the builtin one.  (You could monkeypatch `__builtins__['property']` if you want to get really sneaky.)

Comment: Ooh! The activity on that bug is encouraging! Monekypatching builtins is terrifying! But definitely the the kind of creative answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

What happens in your code:

first case with class `A`:

`>>>print(A().a)`

1. create an instance of `A`
2. access an attribute called `'A'` on the instance

now python, following its data model, trys to find `A.a` using `object.__getattribute__`(since you haven't provided your custom `__getattribute__`)

however :

```
@property
def a(self):
    print "We're here -> attribute lookup found 'a' in one of the usual places!"
    raise AttributeError # <= an AttributeError is raised - now python resorts to '__getattr__'
    return "a" # <= this code is unreachable
```

so, since `__getattribute__` lookup ended with `AttributeError`, it calls your `__getattr__` :

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
...         print "We're here -> attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places!"
...         print('attr: ', name)
...         return "not a" #it returns 'not a'
```

what happens in your second code:

you access `blah.get_thing_three` by `__getattribute__`. since `get_thing_three` fails(no `three` in `things`) with an AttributeError, now your `__getattr__` tries to lookup `get_thing_three` in `things`, which also fails - you get exception for `get_thing_three` because it has higher precedence.

what you can do :

you have to write custom `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` both. but, in most cases it won't get you far, and other people using your code won't expect some custom data protocols.

well, I have an advice for you(I have written a crude mongodb orm that I use internally) : 
don't rely on your `__getattr__` inside your document-to-object mapper. use direct access to document inside your class (I think it doesn't hurt any encapsulation). here's my example:

```
class Model(object):
  _document = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2 }
  def __getattr__(self, name): 
     r"""syntactic sugar for those who are using this class externally. 
     >>>foo = Model()
     >>>foo.a
     1"""

  @property
  def ab_sum(self):
     try :
        return self._document[a] + self._document[b]
     except KeyError:
        raise #something that isn't AttributeError
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got a handle on _why_ it's happening, but it's definitely good to have it re-clarified. The answer I'm looking for, however, is how exactly I might go about writing those custom `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` methods to work the way I want them to.

Comment: I don't think writing a `__getattribute__` will help much, for the reason I mentioned in my answer.  Even if you catch the AttributeError in `__getattribute__`, you'll have the same problem Python already has: how will you tell whether it's a real AttributeError caused by failed lookup, or an error raised from user code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can still get some more ideas flowing in here. Nothing meeting my requirements yet though! It may be impossible, but at least I got a bit closer:

```
>>> class GetChecker(dict):
...     def __getattr__(self, attr):
...         try:
...             return self[attr]
...         except KeyError as e:
...             if hasattr(getattr(type(self), attr), '__get__'):
...                 raise AttributeError('ooh, this is an tricky error.')
...             else:
...                 raise AttributeError(e)
...     
...     @property
...     def get_thing_three(self):
...         return self.three
... 
>>> 
>>> blah = GetChecker({'one': 0})
>>> print(blah.one)
0
>>> print(blah.lalala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __getattr__
AttributeError: type object 'GetChecker' has no attribute 'lalala'
>>> print(blah.get_thing_three)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __getattr__
AttributeError: ooh, this is an tricky error.
>>>
```

At least with this I can provide an error message that hints at how to track down the issue, instead of looking like the issue...

I'm not satisfied yet though. I'll gladly accept an answer that can do better!