# Why does python property decorator eat this exception?

Tags: python, exception, decorator

Nothing prints when I run this code. Why? No exceptions are thrown, nothing in the if...elif...else structure is executed.

Environment: Python 2.7.

```
d= {"x":1}

class bizarre(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.metadata = {}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.metadata.get(name, None)

    @property
    def odd(self):
        if False:
            print '1'
        elif self.fake.get("blah", ''):
            print '2'
        else:
            print '3'

b=bizarre()
b.odd
```

[The previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116896/python-why-is-getattr-catching-attributeerrors) suggested by [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn) has the information needed to answer my question, though not directly. But I can answer my own question now:

The property decorator uses `AttributeError` as a signal from the getter to call `__getattr__`, so if your getter throws an attribute error, it will be caught and you won't see it.

Thank you lemonhead and mission.liao for indulging my ignorance.

Comment: Don't think this is a duplicate, while they have the same cause, the previous question asked about `__getattr__` and this one about the `@property` decorator.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I figured out what is happening here:

```
 elif self.fake.get("blah", ''):
     print '2'
```

This is the problematic line.  `self.fake` is `None`, so running `None.get('blah')` raises an `AttributeError`.  However, since this is inside a property, python treats this as if the property does not exist, and so in turn calls `__getattr__`, which does not print anything

Comment: I didn't know that was how the property decorator worked. Thanks, @lemonhead

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is you override __getattr__ method

bizarre.odd would be called as expected when you remove bizarre.__getattr__.

Comment: hmm... but it looks like bizarre.odd is still getting called?

Comment: Yes. If you put `try/except` in it, you will see that it fails with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` (because `self.fake` is `None`, then you call `get` on it); but the error is silently swallowed. I am not smart enough to figure out why, but [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/848460-property-decorator-doesnt-raise-exceptions) is a largish discussion on it. `odd` is certainly being called.

Comment: You are right, I missed something here

Comment: @Amadan, yeah gotcha had just come to the same conclusion.